# How i could get all the images from a specific folder in S3 bucket with React and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to get all the images from a S3 Bucket.

- I have all the images inside the bucket: communitycore-dev-img
- I split the images in different paths (groups or folders).
- I just want to render all the images inside the path "avatars/default/"

As you can see, de bucket is public: https://communitycore-dev-img.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/default/animal_avatar_20.png

This is the configuration of the AWS S3 Bucket:
The region is: us-east-1

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::communitycore-dev-img/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function ImageGallery() {
  const [imageKeys, setImageKeys] = useState<string[]>([]) as any;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchImages() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://communitycore-dev-img.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=avatars/default/",
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch images");
        }

        // Check if response has data and is not empty
        if (response.status === 204) {
          throw new Error("No data found");
        }

        const responseData = await response.text();
        console.log("Response Data:", responseData);

        // Check if the response data is empty or doesn't start with '[' (indicating JSON array)
        if (!responseData || responseData.trim()[0] !== "[") {
          throw new Error("Invalid response format");
        }

        const data = JSON.parse(responseData);

        if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
          throw new Error("Invalid response format");
        }

        const imageUrls = data.map(
          (item: { Key: string }) =>
            `https://communitycore-dev-img.s3.amazonaws.com/${item.Key}`,
        );

        setImageKeys(imageUrls);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching images:", error);
      }
    }

    fetchImages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
      <div>
        {" "}
        *
        {imageKeys.map((imageUrl: string | undefined, index: any) => (
          // eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-img-element
          <img
            key={index}
            src={imageUrl}
            alt="Gallery Item"
            style={{ maxWidth: "300px", maxHeight: "300px", margin: "10px" }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageGallery;
```

I tested with different codes but i still having problems.

Currently i'm getting the errors:

1. GET https://communitycore-dev-img.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=avatars/default/ 403 (Forbidden)
2. Error fetching images: Error: Failed to fetch images at page-eb0a9af20462ff41.js:1:1169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is making an unauthenticated request to [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html), but your bucket does not support an unauthenticated `s3:ListBucket` action.

If you want to provide this, then add the following to your bucket policy:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::communitycore-dev-img"
}
```

Arguably, a better solution might be for the client to know all the S3 object keys in advance so it doesn't have to list the bucket. Alternatively, populate that list into an S3 object with a known key (e.g. bucketlist.json) that the client has s3:GetObject access to so that it can fetch the list of valid S3 keys.

Comment: I know it should be obvious but do not do this if your bucket has sensitive information that should not be public (e.g. if you name your files with people's emails or something)